# GIT Reset - How to get back to specific state in repository

Tags: git, git-reset

I have a list of commits.

```
abc--most recent
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
```

Now I want to remove/forget the changes from ***abc(most recent commit)*** to ***mno***. I want to do this in local as well as remote branch (It's a seperate branch, Not master). My aim is to completely move back to the repository version ***pqr***. Don't need backup of any changes after commit ***pqr***.

What is easiest and safest way to avoid any further issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of revisions mno to abc from history:

```
git reset --hard pqr
```

Careful not to have uncommitted changes laying around because they will be *busted*. This will require you to force-push into the remote branch.

If you want to keep history then you need a revision *after* abc to go back to the contents of mno:

```
git restore --staged --worktree --source=pqr .
git commit -m "Getting content back to pqr"
```

Comment: Nothing to add about the method, all is fine, but looks like you've confused `mno` and `pqr` (the question itself is unclear). OP wants "*to completely move back to the repository version pqr*" so... reset on `pqr`, not `mno`, right? :-)

Comment: Right. `pqr`! Good catch. Let me correct it. And how is it going, @RomainValeri?

Comment: Not too bad. Take care, my friend.